# JQuery shortcut to select siblings of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At the moment I'm using this

```
$('body').on('click', '#edit_card .ui.menu a.item', function() {
  tab = $(this).closest('.ui.tab.active');
  updateRelationshipsContentCard(tab);
});
```

To try to select the active tab when clicking the a tag, but it is not finding anything, where is my mistake?

```
<div class="ui pointing secondary menu">
    <a class="item" data-tab="1">1</a>
    <a class="item active" data-tab="2">Pessoas</a> <- Clicked this
</div>
<div class="ui tab" data-tab="1">
    <div class="ui basic segment">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui tab active" data-tab="2"> <- Need to select this
    <div class="ui basic segment">
    </div>
</div>
```

I know that using

```
tab = $(this).parent().parent().children('.ui.tab.active');
```

Worked, but I can't see why using `closest` wouldn't

Comment: `.closest()` searches up the DOM and the link you click on has no ancestor with the classes `.ui.tab.active`. It does have a parent with `ui.pointing.secondary.menu` though

Comment: You don't have any `a`s under the `.ui tab active` class div.  `closest` will search for the parents only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.closest()` method](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) will attempt to select any ancestor element that matches the selector that is provided. In other words, it will traverse up the DOM tree and search for an ancestor or parent element that matches the provided selector.

It wasn't working in your case because `.ui.tab.active` isn't an ancestor of the clicked `.item` element.

If you want to use the `.closest()` method, you could use it to select the closest `.ui.menu` element, and then from there select the sibling `.ui.tab.active` element:

```
$(this).closest('.ui.menu').siblings('.ui.tab.active')
```

Based on your code snippet, you could probably also select the closest `#edit_card` ancestor element and then use `.find()` to select the active tab:

```
$(this).closest('#edit_card').find('.ui.tab.active')
```

..or since the `.ui.menu` element is a direct parent, you could merely use the `.parent()` and `.siblings()` methods together (assuming the markup doesn't change):

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.ui.tab.active')
```

Comment: So closest is like a repeated parent() untill it finds the selector or reaches the body?

Comment: @Mojimi - Yes, pretty much, but if it doesn't find any element(s), then nothing is selected. The [documentation on the `.closest()` method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) covers it and details the difference between `.closest()`/`.parents()`.